# Unwanted newlines for a file.write CSV when entries are overfull/too long

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, format, newline

I am trying to write a CSV file with pythons `file.write` but some of the index entries are so long that they are making new lines in the CSV file. I am using the `.format()` method to fill my columns with their respective input in a loop. Ideally I would like the CSV to accept long entries and just change the column width instead of bumping them to a new row.

```
with tf.Session(config=sess_config) as sess:
        ...

        fclog = open(os.path.join(log_dir, args.fpred + '.csv'), 'w')   # Initialize csv with col headers
        fclog.write("fname,itp,tp_prob,its,ts_prob\n")

        for i in range(len(fname_batch)):
               fclog.write(
               "{},{},{},{},{}\n".format(fname_batch[i].decode(), picks_batch[i][0][0], picks_batch[i][0][1],
                                                picks_batch[i][1][0], picks_batch[i][1][1]))
        ...
        fclog.close()
```

[image: ![Sample rows of csv output]

The image above is a sample of rows from the resultant csv file. Notice that the first row of entries is not overfull and works as expected. However the second row of entries contains an overfull entry in the `tp_prob` column and bumps the rest of the entries to a new line. The third row of entries works as expected again.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that for some reason line breaks `\n` were being added inside the actual row strings when the data was too long instead of just at the end of the row. To fix this I used the `.replace` function to replace the line breaks in the row string and then added a single line break back to the end of the row.

```
with tf.Session(config=sess_config) as sess:
        ...

        fclog = open(os.path.join(log_dir, args.fpred + '.csv'), 'w')   # Initialize csv with col headers
        fclog.write("fname,itp,tp_prob,its,ts_prob\n")

        for i in range(len(fname_batch)):
               my_str = "{},{},{},{},{}".format(fname_batch[i].decode(), picks_batch[i][0][0],
                                                picks_batch[i][0][1],
                                                picks_batch[i][1][0],
                                                picks_batch[i][1][1]).replace("\n", "")
               fclog.write(my_str + "\n")
        ...
        fclog.close()
```

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this so I welcome more solutions. I also still do not understand why these line breaks are being automatically inserted.